# Python turtle Stuck on input and program keeps not responding

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple code in python, tried on MS Visual Studio, Pycharm, Eclipse and none works. After I press run the button, the applications open and gets unresponsive. Any idea? I am running on Windows 10 64. Did I miss something?

```
import os
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("primul")


border_pen=turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("blue")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

player=turtle.Turtle()
player.color("red")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0,-250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed=15
def move_left():
    x=player.xcor()
    x-=playerspeed
    player.setx(x)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left,"Left")


delay=input("press enter")
```

Comment: remove the `input('press enter')`?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with code :
 You are waiting on `input('press enter')` which will halt the GUI frame. You need to replace it with `wn.mainloop()` which will prevent you screen from exiting .

```
import os
import turtle
import tkinter

wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("primul")


border_pen=turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("blue")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

player=turtle.Turtle()
player.color("red")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0,-250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed=15
def move_left():
    x=player.xcor()
    x-=playerspeed
    player.setx(x)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left,"Left")

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you sir , you are a saviour.